# Automatically created ingress firewall rules for Google Kubernetes Engine cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

When deploying a cluster to a single zone/network, there are some firewall rules automatically created by GKE. Trying to get clarification for all of these currently, but failing with one of these rules.

- Rule 1: For this I need clarification
- Rule 2: Range containing exactly one IP which is the Master
- Rule 3: Enable networking between different regions/zones for the network 'default'

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the rule that allows traffic between pods through the nodes in the cluster.
10.148.0.0/14 is the container address range configured in your cluster.
You can verify it by looking at the properties of your GKE cluster.

I hope this helps.